# Convert comma separated string into list

Tags: php, html, html-lists

I have a string eg:

```
$string = "word1,word2,word3,word4";
```

I need to echo this into `<li>` elements using PHP. So `$string` becomes:

```
<li>word1</li>
<li>word2</li>
<li>word3</li>
<li>word4</li>
```

Comment: StackOverflow is a Q&A site, not a "please provide the code" site. Please at least give it your best shot before posting a question.

Comment: Read [the manual page for `str_getcsv()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like this:

```
$string = "word1,word2,word3,word4";
$string = explode(",",$string);
foreach ($string as $str) {
    echo "<li>".$str."</li>";
}
```

You can `explode()` the string into an array, loop through it, and output the results into a list option.

Comment: `explode`, not `implode`.

Comment: that's right, I always get them confused

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
echo "<li>" . str_replace ("," , "</li><li>" , $string) . "</li>";
```

For what you are trying to accomplish, the explode approach adds unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Why is `explode()` overhead?

Comment: Stuffing everything into an array and then looping as opposed to one line of code using a highly optimized replace function.

Comment: How do you know that's optimized? It's less code yes, but is it faster?

Comment: Counting the number of string instantiations that occur alone should make it clear that it will be faster.  It will be difficult to prove this though without a pretty large list.  Also, I like your explode answer if the user needs to do anything with the element inside the loop.  Since, she does not, just giving the user another option that I like better.

Comment: `str_replace()` and `explode()` both loop through characters in the string, David's `str_replace()` solution would be faster, as the `explode()` solution just adds another loop to the code.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this

```
$string = "word1,word2,word3,word4";
echo "<ul>";
foreach(explode(',', $string) as $li) {
    echo "<li>$li</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

[**DEMO.**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/65QKRV)