# explode the retrieved values from db and display it in list view in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

**Controllercode:**

```
    public function testjoin()
    {
        $test=supportedversionsModel::join('MainHaghway', 'MainHaghway.buildid', '=','HaghwaySupports.build_id')
        ->select('MainHaghway.versions','HaghwaySupports.supportedversions','MainHaghway.timestamputc','MainHaghway.updatedescription','MainHaghway.checkcount','MainHaghway.statuscode')->get();
        return view('haghwayUpdate',compact('test'));

    }
}
```

Here I have joined two tables which has one to many relationship.And returning the results to the view.

**View code:**

```
      <table class="table" id="table">

        <thead>
          <tr class="header">
              <th valign="middle" width="3%">Versions</th>
              <th valign="middle" width="2%">Supportedversions</th>
              <th valign="middle" width="7%">Release Date</th>
              <th valign="middle" width="3%">Type</th>
              <th valign="middle" width="7%">Description</th>
              <th valign="middle" width="3%">Actions</th>
              <th valign="middle" width="3%">Downloader</th>
              <th valign="middle" width="3%">Beta code</th>

            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
             @foreach($test as $user)
             <tr>
            <td>{{$user->versions}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->supportedversions}}</td>
          <td>{{$user->timestamputc}}</td>
          <td><a href="">Groups</a></td>
          <td>{{$user->updatedescription}}</td>
          <td>{{$user->statuscode}}</td>
          <td>{{$user->checkcount}}</td>
         **<td>{{"<li>" . str_replace ("," , "</li><li>" , $user->supportedversions) . "</li>"}}</td>**
          <td></td>


            </tr>
          @endforeach

            </tbody>

                </table>
```

This is my view code. Here I am just displaying the retrieved values in table.[image: The attached image file is the table view that displays the db values. But here in the second column holds the imploded values,there I need to explode the values and display it in list view.]

Comment: Are you storing html data in database ?

Comment: Yes I am storing the html data into database

Comment: if you don't want those tag means . then why your storing those tags in database ? and also storing html in database is not good idea .

Comment: Sorry,I am not storing the data with the tags. And I'm inserting those values with the selection of multiselect box and imploded those values and done inserting

Comment: But on displaying and I need to explode the ',' and display the values in list view

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19728572/convert-comma-seperated-string-into-list--->this is the one I needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can understand what you need to do.

As per [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#components-and-slots) about slot i.e. `{{ }}`. Anything written inside `{{ }}` except variables are considered as string (Its `echo` in Laravel).

So as per your requirement, you should use `{!! !!}`, which more advance and it'll allow you to use HTML Elements as string. You'll find more detailed info in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35031303/5350773).

Comment: It removes the tags but echoes with braces

Comment: ie. {
1.0.0.3
}

Comment: oh silly mistake.. use `{!! !!}` instead of `{{!! !!}}` :)

Comment: You're Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to decode html entities. For example `<p>some text </p>` if you see this and you want to convert into paragraph then used this

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes($your_variable)); ?>
```

for more details please read [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Answer (score 0):

**1st :** you missed `Ul` or `OL` tag  that's why it's not listing

**Note :** `li` tag should be enclosed by `ul` tag `ol` tag

**2nd :**  use `strip_tags()` function strips a string from HTML, XML, and PHP tags.

**3rd:**  use {!! .. !!}

```
 <td>{!! "<ul><li>" . str_replace ("," , "</li><li>" , strip_tags($user->supportedversions)) . "</li> </ul>" !!}</td>
```

Comment: No sir it is listing the values.But it displays with the tags.I don't want the tags on listing

Comment: use strip_tags($user->supportedversions)

Comment: i think your doing something wrong . strip_tags will work for your need  .read documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: <td>{{"" . str_replace ("," , "</li><li>" , strip_tags($user->supportedversions)) . ""}}</td>-->this is what I have tried inside my view sir. and it displays something like this **1.0.0.2</li><li>1.0.0.3**

Comment: try this one <td>{{"<ul><li>" . str_replace ("," , "</li><li>" , strip_tags($user->supportedversions)) . "</li> </ul>"}}</td>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148850/discussion-between-jyothi-and-nishanthi).